# Is there a way of using PDO::FETCH_ASSOC and PDO::FETCH_OBJ at the same time?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

It's possible to display records from database two different ways at the same time using PDO? What I mean is I want to echo records as object and array at the same time.

I tried using `$db_conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_BOTH);` but it's not working. I get this error which I know what it means : `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object`

Also i set as this with the same result:

```
$db_conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$db_conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

And when I try to fetch data from the database I use:

```php
$db_conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=utf8', $db_user, $db_pass, array(
                        PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true
                ));
```

```php
$sql = $db_conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM table_name');
$sql->execute();
$all_data = $sql->fetchAll();
foreach($all_data as $row){
    echo $row->col1;
    echo $row['col1'];
}
```

Comment: Why the downvote? I think it's a pretty legitimate question...

Comment: Please show your entire DB connection setup code.

Comment: @JonStirling, I've updated my question with that.

Comment: the error message indicates that `$db_conn` is not an object, which means that the database connection failed. you should focus on this.

Comment: Either `$row` is an array or an object, it can't be both at the same time.

Comment: Instead of setting the fetch style on the connection, you could pass the it to the fetch method directly. `$sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);` and `$sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` and call fetch 2 times.

Comment: @Barmar, that was my question. So you say it can't be used both at the same time?! I think that is pretty weird not to. Or am I missing something.

Comment: @enricog, I tried that too, No errors, but no records showing.

Comment: If your objective is to fetch the data as array and as object, then I'd do a "dirty" hack to get it working quickly. You `$sql>execute()`  first, then `$arr = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` = array is created. Then, the dirty part: perform `$sql->execute();` again and `$obj = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);`. Note: I never needed to fetch object / array at the same time. Note 2: the above "hack" will actually execute the query twice. If I were you, I'd do what Barmar wrote in his answer - fetch once, then manipulate the output when I need it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a class that implements the [`ArrayAccess`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) interface, so the properties can be accessed using array syntax. Then you can do:

```
$db_conn->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'YourClass');
```

The documentation link above has an example of a simple class definition.

Comment: Haven't tried it, but I don't see why it shouldn't.